# Let $V$ be a vector space and $T$ be a linear map on $V$. Suppose that $\text{dim null}(T^2) = 5$. Prove that $\text{dim null}(T) \ge 3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $T$ be a linear map on $V$. Suppose that $\text{dim null}(T^2) = 5$. Prove that $\text{dim null}(T) \ge 3$.

I can come up with a sort of heuristic argument: if $\text{dim null}(T) < 3$, then when applying $T$ to $\text{range}(T) (\subset V)$, the dimension of the null space can grow by at most 2. Hence $\text{dim null}(T^2) < 5$. However, I cannot figure out how to formulate this idea rigorously.

Comment: Notice that $T$ restricts to a linear map from $\mathrm{null}(T^2)$ to $\mathrm{null}(T)$. What can you say about the dimensions of the nullspace and the range of that map?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write the Kernel of $T^2$ as a sum of vector spaces
$$\ker T + \ker T_{|T(V)}.$$ The sum is not direct, but assuming the dimension of $\ker T$ to be smaller than $2$ like you did, it can add up to at most Dimension $4$.
If you wann, I can help you clarify why the sum above is equal to $\ker T^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $W=\ker(T^2)$. $W$ is invariant under $T$. Therefore, we can consider $T_w = T\rvert_W$ the operator $T$ restricted to $W$.

Since $\ker (T) \subset \ker(T^2) = W$, it follows that $\ker(T_w) = \ker(T)$.

On the other hand, $(T_w)^2\equiv 0$, so the minimal polynomial of $T_w$ is either $x$ or $x^2$.

If $T_w\equiv 0$, then $\ker(T_w) = W$, and we are done. Otherwise, its minimal polynomial is $x^2$, so the maximum order of the Jordan blocks corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ is $2$. Since $\dim W = 5$, there are at least $3$ Jordan blocks for the eigenvalue $0$, which implies $\dim \ker (T)\geq 3$, as desired.